# what is an answer versus a comment to a self-study question

Tags: discussion, answers, comment, homework

We don't just post answers to self-study questions where we give the proof of whatever the OP is asking. I think this is a good policy. However, that seems to mean that any post in response to a self-study question is going to be more like a comment and dialogue, at least according to the usual rules about .

What would warrant an answer to a self-study question as opposed to a comment?

Comment: What I have sometimes done is engage the OP in a conversation to help them figure it out for themselves. When they have, I convert the info from the comments into an official answer.  Another possibility is to post a hint that should be enough to get them past the stumbling block, but doesn't answer the Q for them, as an answer, & have the discussion below that ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/58718/7290) is an example where I did that).